# How to prevent PyTest to execute time.sleep() when collecting?

Tags: python, pytest

I've observed long collecting time when I have `time.sleep(1)` in my tests.

When there is no sleep or it is zero `time.sleep(0)` the collecting is immediate - no delay at all.

I have `time.sleep(1)` in only one place, common for all my 4 tests. When I put `time.sleep(1)` I expect total time to be increased by 4 seconds, but it is increased by 8 seconds!

Here are some results:

```
time.sleep(0): 2 failed, 2 passed in 0.70s
time.sleep(1): 1 failed, 3 passed in 8.69s
time.sleep(2): 1 failed, 3 passed in 16.70s
time.sleep(3): 1 failed, 3 passed in 24.67s
```

Here is the file with tests (sleep_collecting_problem.py):

```python
import pytest
import unittest
import time

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("one_time_set_up", "set_up")
class SleepProblem(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_1(self):
        time.sleep(1)

    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_2(self):
        time.sleep(1)

    @pytest.mark.run(order=3)
    def test_3(self):
        time.sleep(1)

    @pytest.mark.run(order=4)
    def test_4(self):
        time.sleep(1)
```

...the content of my main.py:

```python
import unittest
import pytest
from sleep_collecting_problem import SleepProblem

@pytest.yield_fixture()
def set_up():
    yield

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class")
def one_time_set_up():
    pass

unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SleepProblem))
```

I run it with `pytest -v src/main.py`

pytest: **6.0.1**, Python: **3.7.5**, Platform: Linux-4.15.0-65-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic

Comment: Did you take into consideration the running time of the script?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Running time of which script? Total collecting and execution time without sleep is 0.7s. With sleep(1) it is 8.69s instead of ~4.7s.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question. Using `time.sleep` in tests shouldn't affect the collection time, as the tests are not executed yet - you have probably placed `time.sleep` at module level, or in custom hooks.

Comment: I've added the example in the question @hoefling. I've also observed that this happens only when there is no main method!

Comment: Remove or comment out the `unittest.TextTestRunner...` line. Run `pytest src/main.py -s` to see what happens - first you collect and run the tests with the `python -m unittest` runner, then collect and run tests with `pytest` again. `pytest` has its own runner and will ignore what `unittest` does, anyway.

Comment: A couple of things: your example is still not reproducible - please try to make a reproducible example the next time. It is not a good idea to mix `unittest` with `pytest` in new code - don't derive from `unittest.TestCase` (and don't use the testrunner, as mentioned by @hoefling). And note that test collection means the phase that the tests are discovered, not when they are executed - you should use test _execution_, not collection, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, this is what happens, I just realize it :) Thank you @hoefling! Please, add this as answer to mark it as solved.

Comment: Is it reproducible now, @MrBeanBremen ?

Comment: Yes, it is - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `pytest src/main.py`, the line

```
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SleepProblem))
```

on module level has the following effect: `pytest` tries to collect the test cases from this file, executing the tests with the `unittest` framework, but hiding the output because the stdout is captured. Then it executes the collected tests again, but now with its own runner. If you disable output capturing, you should see something similar to

```
collecting ...  # pytest collection starts and triggers unittest runner
test_1 ... ok   # time.sleep here
test_2 ... ok   # time.sleep here
...

--------------------
Ran N tests

OK  # unittest finishes

collected 4 items  # pytest runs the tests now

src/main.py::test_1 PASSED
src/main.py::test_2 PASSED
...
```

If you need to support `unittest`, wrap the runner in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block to avoid triggering it with `pytest`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(...)
```

and run `python src/main.py` to start a `unittest` run.

Or just use the builtin discovery from the command line and drop the custom runner alltogether:

```
$ python -m unittest discover -s src -t src -p sleep*
```